# xterm active line screen position

Tags: cursor-position, xterm, x11

Is it possible to configure the active line in an xterm window to appear somewhere other than the bottom of the screen?

While there are advantages, my monitor is not positioned for the bottom of the screen to be most easily reachable. It conflicts with a web browser's address bar being at the top of the screen.

I'd like to position the active line, say, 2/3rds down my window.

Comment: I think OP referes to the shell prompt.

Comment: Yes, the prompt basically. The line where text appears if you press buttons on your keyboard.